# How to move money with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, locking

```
Account has embedded
  Transactions
    amount (positive for received transactions, negative for outgoing transactions)
```

User wants to send money. We need to compute account's balance to check if there is enough money. In pseudocode:

```
send_money(amount)
  balance = sum(account's all transactions) // Mongo Query 1
  if (amount <= balance)
    add a new transaction to account // Mongo Query 2
```

But isn't it possible that two concurrent mongo connections both pass Query 1 and proceed to make Query 2? Say user's balance is 1 and two concurrent send money requests worth of 1 come at the same time passing Query 1 and are successfully added to transactions. In effect, the user ends up with a balance of -1.

How is this prevented?

Comment: Havent you looked at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ ?

Comment: Looks like a nice solution. I wonder how using a separate lock collection compares to the Update If Current pattern?

Comment: The update if current would for one only work for the same document, not multiple documents

Comment: Update if current is just designed to ensure you update the most reent document, it isn't a transaction across many documents like what your looking for

Answer (score 2):

When your use-case requires transactions which span multiple documents, MongoDB is usually a bad fit for it, because it doesn't support atomic operations when more than one document is affected.

A possible workaround is the [two-phase-commit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) model.

It basically means that you first add a description what you want to do to each document as an additional field to it. Then you perform an atomic operation on each document which applies that action and removes the description. Each of these steps is confirmed by querying the document afterwards and each step of the transaction is documented by a 3rd document in an additional collection of pending transactions. This allows you to check for pending transactions and roll them back.

This method is hard to implement and has considerable overhead. Before you implement this, you should really consider if there is really a good reason no to use a database system with native transaction support.

Comment: What about the Update If Current pattern? Is it more lightweight?

Comment: @randomguy This answer was a reaction on your comment to PKDs answer where you asked what to do when two collections are affected. The UpdateIfCurrent pattern is another scenario: two threads trying to change the same object. This is a simpler case with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Update If Current pattern outlined here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/ with perhaps the suggestion "Add a version variable to the document that applications increment upon each update operation" discussed near the base of that page? You will probably need to track the current balance in a field in the document in addition to the array of transactions. So your update section will likely require an $inc of 1 on your version field, an $inc of the +/- amount on the balance field and a $push for the new transaction element in the array.

Comment: Would the Update If Current pattern work if the transactions were in a separate collection?

Comment: Your original question was asking what happens if two concurrent client threads attempt to update the *same* document. If you are really asking "how can one single transaction span both (1) the debit of money from one document and (2) the credit of money into a separate document, atomically", then you will need an approach similar to 2PC, like Sammaye linked to.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be a problem anymore beyond next summer. MongoDB will add support for multi-document transactions in version 4.0, so we will have ACID guarantees in multi-document transactions like in RBDMS systems.

Now, MongoDB use cases will fit all those you can work with!

Check this post: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb?jmp=community